# How to validate/syntax-check JSP taglibs?

Tags: debugging, jsp, taglib

At work I currently write a lot of custom JSP-Tags for our designers, which are written in JSP's XML flavour (rather than Java classes).

When I typo'ed or made a mistake and try to load the TLDs or tag files, Tomcat always just throws the non-descript error:  `Could not add one or more tag libraries.`

Now I have to hunt around the taglibs finding out which one is borked and do trial and error - noone's preferred way of debugging.

Eclipse is unfortunately [useless](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.webtools/msg16268.html) at validating taglibs.

Are there any tools around that could help me? The icing on the cake would be Maven integration. I have tried this [plugin](http://maven-taglib.sourceforge.net/m2/), but no luck.

Comment: Unfortunately your "useless" link is broken, however the XML flavor should be able to make use of the XML Validator.

Comment: There is a plugin called "Ganymede"

See if the below link helps

[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144058/eclipse-ganymede-not-validating-jsps-properly

Comment: My advice is to move on Intellij idea, it has a great validation tools.